# Not able to send Json data to controller method using $Post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, post, jquery-post

I am trying to send Json data to my controller method using $.post of Jquery.

Js code :

```
      $.post(saveUpdateActionurl, JSON.stringify({ 'name': "John", 'time':   "2pm"      }), function (data) {
        _this.afterSave(data); 
    }, "json");
```

Controller Method :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ControllerMethod(Test data)
    {
       return null; 
    }

 public class Test  
 {
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string time {get;set;}

 }
```

The controller method parameter receives null for the property name and time. 
I am not using form in UI so cant use the form collection. 
How to resolve this?

Comment: Just `{ 'name': "John", 'time':  "2pm" }` (not `JSON.stringify({ 'name': "John", 'time':  "2pm"  }`

Comment: @Stephen - Thanks. I am trying this. Will update.

Comment: @Stephen - It did not work for me. I again got both the properties in the Test Object as null.

Comment: I want to use an object as a parameter only in the method not have separate parameters one each for each property in the object.

Comment: Then that is exactly what the code in my comment will do! If its not working its due to other problems with the code you have not shown us. `$.post(saveUpdateActionurl, { 'name': "John", 'time': "2pm" }, function(data) { ... } });` will work fine.

Comment: @stephen - It worked for me. Had some compile issues. Thanks a lot